# Mac M1 .BF Compiler in Rust

Tags: rust, assembly, brainfuck, compiler

I'm writing a brainfuck compiler in rust, that takes brainfuck instructions and converts them to a very basic assembly form, and then compiles that into binary, if you are not familiar with brainfuck I have included some resources, but the basic premise is this, the language operates with a memory tape, and there are 8 commands, the functions below correspond very crudely to the assembly for each command. If someone could verify that my Assembly associations are correct I would appreciate that greatly as I am not very comfortable in assembly.

[My Projects Repo](https://github.com/Jakersnell/zombie)

[Brainf*ck wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck)

I could really use help perfecting the whole project, but this is just about the assembly.

```
use std::process::Command;

pub trait InstructionSet {
    const ENTRY_POINT: &'static str;
    const FILE_EX: &'static str;
    fn compile_to_bin_cmd(filename: &str) -> Vec<Command>;
    fn initialize_header() -> String;
    fn generate_inc_ptr() -> String;
    fn generate_dec_ptr() -> String;
    fn generate_inc_val() -> String;
    fn generate_dec_val() -> String;
    fn generate_lp_start(loop_label: &str) -> String;
    fn generate_lp_end(loop_label: String) -> String;
    fn generate_read() -> String;
    fn generate_write() -> String;
    fn initialize_footer() -> String;
}

pub(crate) struct M1;
impl InstructionSet for M1 {
    const ENTRY_POINT: &'static str = "_main";
    const FILE_EX: &'static str = ".s";

    fn compile_to_bin_cmd(filename: &str) -> Vec<Command> {
        let mut cmd = Command::new("gcc");
        cmd.args(["-o", &filename, &(filename.to_owned() + Self::FILE_EX)]);
        vec![cmd]
    }

    fn initialize_header() -> String {
        format!(
            "
.data
    .p2align 2
    MEM:
        .zero 4096

.section    __TEXT,__text,regular,pure_instructions
.build_version macos, 13, 0
.global {0}                           ; -- Begin function main

.p2align 2
{0}:
    ; init mem ptr
    adrp    x10, MEM@PAGE
    add     x10, x10, MEM@PAGEOFF

    ; value register
    mov     w12, #0

        ",
            Self::ENTRY_POINT
        )
    }

    fn generate_inc_ptr() -> String {
        "
    strb     w12, [x10]     ; inc ptr
    add      x10, x10, #1
    ldrb     w12, [x10]
        "
        .to_string()
    }

    fn generate_dec_ptr() -> String {
        "
    strb    w12, [x10]
    sub     x10, x10, #1
    ldrb    w12, [x10]
        "
        .to_string()
    }

    fn generate_inc_val() -> String {
        "
    ldrb    w12, [x10]
    add     w12, w12, #1
    strb    w12, [x10]
        "
        .to_string()
    }

    fn generate_dec_val() -> String {
        "
    ldrb    w12, [x10]
    sub     w12, w12, #1
    strb    w12, [x10]
        "
        .to_string()
    }

    fn generate_lp_start(loop_label: &str) -> String {
        format!(
            "
.p2align 2
loop_{}: // loop start
            ",
            loop_label
        )
    }

    fn generate_lp_end(loop_label: String) -> String {
        format!(
            "
    ldrb    w12, [x10]
    cbz     w12, loop_{} // loop end
            ",
            loop_label
        )
    }

    fn generate_read() -> String {
        "
    mov     x1, x10  ; read byte from stdin
    mov     x0, #1
    mov     x2, #1
    mov     x16, #3
    svc     0
        "
        .to_string()
    }

    fn generate_write() -> String {
        "
    mov     x0, #1  ; write byte to stdout
    mov     x1, x10
    mov     x2, #1
    mov     x16, #4
    svc     0
        "
        .to_string()
    }

    fn initialize_footer() -> String {
        "
.p2align 2
end:               ; exit with status 0
    mov     x0, #0
    mov     x16, #1
    svc     0
    "
        .to_string()
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Reviewers are only able to review code embedded here. ["_You may optionally also link to a third-party site where your programming project is hosted, but the question must contain enough code to stand on its own._"](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3653/120114) If you are concerned about the size of your code, bear in mind that [the character limit on Code Review was increased to 65k](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7163/120114).